# Как составить sql запрос с созданием нескольких групп из связанной таблицы?

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно получить количество файлов форматов cdr и dxf для каждой записи таблицы table1. и найти записи для которых есть 2 cdr файла и 4 dxf файла.

> ```
> create table table1
> (
>    id int, 
>    name varchar(255)
> );
> ```

> ```
> create table table2
> (
>    id int,
>    table1_id int,
>    filename varchar(255),
>    filetype varchar(255)
> );
> ```

> ```
> insert into table1 (id,name) values
> (123, 'name123'),
> (124, 'name124'),
> (125, 'name125'),
> (126, 'name126'),
> (127, 'name127'),
> (128, 'name128')
> ```

> ```
> insert into table2 (id,table1_id,filename,filetype) values
> (1, 123, 'file1', 'cdr'),
> (2, 123, 'file1', 'dxf'),
> (3, 123, 'file2', 'cdr'),
> (4, 123, 'file2', 'dxf'),
> (5, 123, 'file3', 'dxf'),
> (6, 123, 'file4', 'dxf'),
> (7, 124, 'file11', 'cdr'),
> (8, 124, 'file11', 'dxf'),
> (9, 124, 'file12', 'cdr'),
> (10, 124, 'file12', 'dxf')
> ```

> ```
> select * from table1
> ```
>
> ```
>  id | name   
> --: | :------
> 123 | name123
> 124 | name124
> 125 | name125
> 126 | name126
> 127 | name127
> 128 | name128
> ```

> ```
> select * from table2
> ```
>
> ```
> id | table1_id | filename | filetype
> -: | --------: | :------- | :-------
>  1 |       123 | file1    | cdr     
>  2 |       123 | file1    | dxf     
>  3 |       123 | file2    | cdr     
>  4 |       123 | file2    | dxf     
>  5 |       123 | file3    | dxf     
>  6 |       123 | file4    | dxf     
>  7 |       124 | file11   | cdr     
>  8 |       124 | file11   | dxf     
>  9 |       124 | file12   | cdr     
> 10 |       124 | file12   | dxf
> ```

> ```
> -- пример рабочего запроса. но в нем только по типу cdr ищется.
>
> SELECT table1.id, count(table2.filetype) as cdrCount
> FROM table1
> INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
> WHERE table2.filetype = 'cdr'
> GROUP BY table2.table1_id, table2.filetype
> HAVING COUNT(table2.filetype) = 2
> ```
>
> ```
>  id | cdrCount
> --: | -------:
> 123 |        2
> 124 |        2
> ```

> ```
> -- ЭТОТ ЗАПРОС НЕ РАБОТАЕТ
>
> -- Ожидаемый результат:
> -- ----------------------------
> -- | id  | cdrCount | dxfCount |
> -- |-----|----------|----------|
> -- | 123 |    2     |    4     |  
> -- -----------------------------
>
> SELECT table1.id, count(t21.filetype) as cdrCount, count(t22.filetype) as dxfCount
> FROM table1
> INNER JOIN table2 t21 ON table1.id = t21.table1_id
> INNER JOIN table2 t22 ON table1.id = t22.table1_id
> WHERE t21.filetype = 'cdr' AND t22.filetype = 'dxf'
> GROUP BY t21.table1_id, t21.filetype, t22.table1_id, t22.filetype
> HAVING COUNT(t21.filetype) = 2 AND COUNT(t22.filetype) = 4
> ```
>
> ```
> id | cdrCount | dxfCount
> -: | -------: | -------:
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b31ef2f8579ddcc5eb47e76e5930d573)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT table1.id, 
       SUM(table2.filetype = 'cdr') as cdrCount, 
       SUM(table2.filetype = 'dxf') as dxfCount
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
WHERE table2.filetype IN ('cdr', 'dxf')
GROUP BY table1.id
HAVING cdrCount = 2 AND dxfCount = 4
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=715fbae08974ee0d5308d42bcf2fdcfb